Formatação do código em python influencia diretamente no funcionamento e desenvolvimento?
No uso da biblioteca tkinter em python, a formatação do código na questão de espaços em branco
no mesmo influência diretamente no uso do programa? Para mim, é mais confortável de gerenciar de modo que os parênteses abram e fechem de modo isolado, para que fique algo mais parecido à CSS.
        self.root.title("Objetivos do Dia")
        self.root.configure(
            bg="#466068"
            )
        self.root.geometry("1200x900")
        self.root.minsize(
            width=1200, 
            height=900
            )

ao invés de:
        self.root.title("Objetivos do Dia")
        self.root.configure(bg="#466068")
        self.root.geometry("1200x900")
        self.root.minsize(width=1200, height=900)

Embora me pareça mais cômodo, não sei se seria uma boa prática para um possível projeto em equipe.

acredito que espaços não atrapalham em nada, quanto ao trabalho em equipe é algo  a se combinar para se ter o mesmo estilo em todo o codigo

Antes de mais nada, espaços são significativos no começo das linhas em Python, e complementando, apesar da pergunta ser sobre barra, a resposta desta postagem já explica o comportamento de espaços entre ( )

Para o seu caso não irá alterar a funcionalidade do código.
De acordo com a documentação oficial do Python quanto à análise léxica a utilização de espaços em branco na separação de tokens da linguagem é livre, sem sentido próprio, exceto no início de uma linha lógica ou dentro de uma string literal. No seu caso, como está separando os tokens referentes aos parâmetros de uma função/método, o espaço em branco não tem sentido especial e será ignorado pelo interpretador, desta forma você pode optar livremente pela sintaxe que mais lhe agrada - mas eu recomendo fortemente ser consistente em toda a aplicação uma vez que decida qual utilizar.
Em contrapartida, como comentado na documentação, no início de uma linha lógica os espaços em branco servirão para definir a indentação e, com isso, a hierarquia dos blocos lógicos no Python, fazendo que você tenha que seguir algumas regras para que o código seja corretamente interpretado. Mesmo que a linguagem te dê liberdade em escolher quantos espaços em branco usará para a indentação é estritamente necessário que seja coerente dentro do mesmo bloco lógico uma vez que alterando esse padrão um erro ocorrerá em tempo de execução.
Para mais detalhes, recomendo ler a documentação da Análise Léxica do Python, em especial:

Concatenação implícita de linhas
Linhas em branco
Indentação

